# Entity Framework. got "Attaching an entity of type 'X' failed ... " error when deleting and modifying elements on a list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I`m trying to compare 2 lists and make proper changes to database.

Given an `OldList` and a `NewList` I compare both and decide what elements should be deleted, inserted or just modified.

Given this both lists:

- `OldList` contains Ids `1`,`2` and `3`
- `NewList` contains Ids `1` and `3`

then, the item with id `2` should be removed, and the items with ids `1` and `3` should be modified.

This is my function

```
if (OldList != null && NewList != null) {

    // get modifications
    var deleted = (from item in OldList where !NewList.Any(c => c.Id == item.Id) select item).ToList();
    var modified = (from item in NewList where OldList.Any(c => c.Id == item.Id) select item).ToList();
    var added = (from item in NewList where !OldList.Any(c => c.Id == item.Id) select item).ToList();

    // change state to added, modified or delete ones
    modified.ForEach(item => db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified);
    deleted.ForEach(item => db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted);
    added.ForEach(item => db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added);
}
```

When I run it, then I got the fallowing error executing the `EntityState.Deleted` line cause the `EntityState.Modified` was already executed:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Attaching an entity of type 'X' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

**In fact. the real problem is. Attaching elements from different lists (`OldList` and `NewList`)**

It seems that, when I add an element from a list, all other elements on that list is attached too.

How can I be able to compare two lists, set the items states and avoid this error?

Comment: Daniel, you need to show more code. How do you keep/update those oldlist and newlist variables. How do you manage your context ( `db`). What kind of (if any) code generation strategy you are using with EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my friend. You can use Intersect and Except Operator in LinQ.

```
var lstModified = OldList.Intersect(NewList); //return 1, 3 

var lstDeleted = OldList.Except(NewList); //return 2
```

You can visit this link to refer more:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Set-Operators-374f34fe

Comment: thanks for advice, however it does not works because the items in the list are not the same object. The only thing in common is the ID. This way i should use id comparator anyway.